# How to make Document Viewer allow me to scroll through the pages?

Tags: pdf, evince, scrolling

I am currently in the process of building an LFS system, and the LFS book comes in the format of a >300 page long PDF file. I am reading it via Ubuntu's default document viewer, and when I started I was able to scroll through the pages using my touchpad fine. Now, however, I can only scroll through the contents of one page, and must press <kbd>N</kbd> to get to the next page. I have restarted Document Viewer but to no avail.

How can I change this annoying functionality, so that I am able to scroll through as I normally would?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you want is called "continuous" scrolling. The location of the setting might differ from version to version. In Ubuntu GNOME 16.04:

[image]

In older versions and in Unity, I think it might be in the "View" menu.

Assuming the keyboard shortcut hasn't changed, try pressing <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I wonder why this intuitive behavior isn't the default one (at least in version 3.34). It is the default in all Windows' PDF readers I know.