# Document viewer locks scrolling at bottoms of pages

Tags: keyboard, pdf, evince

I use the down arrow key to scroll through PDF documents in document viewer.

However, when I reach the end of the page it does not scroll to the next page, and stays on the current page. Video: https://www.loom.com/share/6c724012ab9b44d789e1907fba262e44

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the settings (the three vertical bars) then you will find a checkbox called continuous. Make sure this checkbox is on an then it should work.

Actually this other question has a more detailed answer:
[How to make Document Viewer allow me to scroll through the pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786717/how-to-make-document-viewer-allow-me-to-scroll-through-the-pages)